# Do Samsung finger scanners constantly use battery if you keep your finger on the sensor without needing to scan anything?

Tags: samsung, android-12, sensors

I'm using the Samsung A32 5G.

It has a finger sensor that allows the phone to be unlocked, I'm wondering if the phone is on and you constantly keep your finger on that sensor, will it continue to try to pick up a fingerprint and use up battery, or will it only use battery when it is actively asking for a fingerprint to be scanned?

Do you not have to worry about leaving your fingerprint randomly on the sensor which could waste battery?

Comment: As far as I know a fingerprint sensor never draws much power even when active. Additionally in my understanding a fingerprint sensor is like a camera sensor - it is always "ready to work" (finger on sensor, light on camera sensor) but unless instructed by the software to do its job it remains in sleep mode (inactive).

Comment: I tried `adb logcat` on Samsung Galaxy M21 and it doesn't output anything when I put my finger on the fingerprint scanner while there's nothing requested for it, unlike when unlocking the phone.

Comment: @Robert Thank you! In that case it shouldn't draw any power unless the phone actually requests a scan. I'm assuming that sleep mode does not use any power whatsoever.